# How to analyze this voltage doubler circuitry?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, charge-pump

What does this circuitry used for? How should I analyze? (It is inserted in the capacitor voltage doubler circuitry between the two stages)

[image]

Comment: You haven't shown enough of the circuit. You should also provide a reference if the drawing is not your own work. (This is site policy.)

Comment: That only looks like half a voltage doubler, so the first step is to find the rest of it.

Comment: Yup I drew this circuitry, it is a two stages voltage doubler with diode and capacitors, but with this part in between the two stages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that \$R_1\$ is a pull-up connected to a voltage larger than \$V_{TH,N_2}+V_{D,N_2}\$, this circuit behaves as a charge pump.

At phase one (\$u_1=low\$), \$N_5\$ and \$N_6\$ are off, and \$N_2\$ is on. Hence the capacitor \$C_2\$ is charged to the potential connected to the drain side of \$N_2\$.

Once it is charged, \$u_1\$ can be pulled high (phase two). At this moment, \$N_5\$ and \$N_6\$ are conducting. \$N_5\$ ensures that \$N_2\$ is off, therefore the capacitor cannot discharge through it, and \$N_6\$ grounds one of the plates of the capacitor, forcing it to reverse its polarity and discharge towards the node \$N_3\$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! I am still wondering what is the difference for the charge pumps without N5 N6 and R1?

Comment: If there wouldn't be the N6, the left node of the capacitor would be floating if you turned N2 off, thus it would not transfer its charge to the other side. Without N5 it could work as long as the signal u3 was not simply a supply voltage (that's my assumption), but a signal which is synchronized with u1.

Comment: node u3 is connected to a diode then to the supply. So voltage node u3 and R1 is offering a bias current for N2?

Comment: Although the rest of the circuit is not shown. I would believe so.

Comment: Everything clear! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problems. If you think this answered your doubt , you can accept this answer :-)

Comment: yes It did! I totally accept it!!

Comment: Ok. So you can click on the "Accept" button :)

Comment: Ohh I am new here and just saw this function